# How can I share a publication about me in linkedin

Tags: linkedin

I'm a computer engineering student and working for a company in cyber security field. I did something about cyber security 5 years ago and some authors mentioned my name about that in two books and a magazine. How can I share these in my linkedin profile? Under Publications or Honors & Awards?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a web-application-specific question; not a question about navgating the workplace.

Comment: @JimG. even if i asked this in another field, question remains same

Comment: @user3220381 Your question is unclear to me. What is stopping you from sharing your work on your LinkedIn profile?

Comment: _some authors mentioned my name about that in two books and a magazine_ How did they mention your name? By citation of your product or paper?? By acknowledgement? Mentioning your name in the books?

Comment: Did you contribute to these books?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Webapps.SE]

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing that forces you to list it under one or the other, but for Honors&Awards, I would typically expect to see awards you had won, rather than your work being referenced, so make it easy for employers or those reading your LinkedIn profile and place it under Publications, and specifically mention that your work was referenced in books x and y by authors a and b.

Comment: but i can't remove myself from authors section

Comment: If you have a question about LinkedIn functionality, I'd suggest reading their help and support pages

Comment: @user3220381 It is your profile, you are free to remove yourself from the Publication authors if you choose to. You could even delete the Publication entirely from your profile.

Answer (score 3):

> I did something about cyber security 5 years ago and some authors
>   mentioned my name about that in two books and a magazine. How can I
>   share these in my linkedin profile?

This "something about cyber security" should be detailed in your Summary section, since that is what you actually did.

The mentions could also be written about in the Summary as well. Something like "... and it has been referenced in 'This book' by Author X, 'That book' by Author Y, and 'This magazine article'..." perhaps with links to them.

Publications and Honors & Awards are for *your* publications, and *your* honors & awards - neither of which apply in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an opportunity in the academics domain, then you can include in the **summary section** , and the **achievements section**.

The description in the **Achievements** section, can go like this:

> Cited in ________________ by _____ et al. 
>   _______Write the summary of the paper here_________

And in the **Summary** section, you can include this:

Should be preferably in a single line, rather than how you explained in the achievements section.

> Have been cited in the _________ by _______, which deals with _______

In case, you are looking for a job outside the academics domain, the just include in the achievements section, and include a single line in the summary section, which can go like this:

> Cited by three published cyber security publications.